# ¿Cómo lograr hacer esta validación con vuetify?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, validación, vuetify

Estoy trabajando con vuetify y este es mi form

```
<v-form ref="form" v-model="valid" lazy-validation>
  <v-text-field
     v-model="register.email"
     :rules="validations.emailRules"
     label="Correo Electrónico"           
  />
  <v-text-field
     v-model="register.phone"
     :rules="validations.phoneRules"
     label="Télefono"
   />
   <v-text-field
      v-model="register.password"
      :rules="validations.passwordRules"
      @click:append="show1 = !show1"
      :append-icon="show1 ? 'mdi-eye' : 'mdi-eye-off'"
      :type="show1 ? 'text' : 'password'"
      label="Contraseña"
    />
</v-form>
```

Estoy intentando hacer la siguiente validación sobre el form.

- El teléfono o correo electrónico son requeridos (solo uno).
- El teléfono de existir debe de contener 10 números.
- El correo electrónico de existir debe de ser valido.
- La contraseña debe de contener al menos 8 caracteres.
- La contraseña es requerida.

las validaciones las estoy intentando hacer como esta en la documentación de vuetify que pueden consultar en la siguiente liga.

https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/forms/#rules

Mi problema es que la validación que pretendo depende de otro campo y no se como acceder usando la reactividad de vue. Este es mi intento de validación.

```
<script>
export default {
  
  data: () => {
    return {
       register: {
           email: "",
           phone: "",
           password: ""
       },
       validations:{
          emailRules: [
             
             v => {
                if(!!v && !!this.register.phone){
                   return  "El correo electrónico o teléfono es requerido" 
                }
                return null;
             },
             v => /.+@.+\..+/.test(v) || "El correo electrónico debe de ser valido"
          ],
          phoneRules: [
              v => {
                if(!!v && !!this.register.email){
                   return  "El teléfono o correo electrónico es requerido" 
                }
                return null;
              },
              v => v.length != 10 || "El télefono debe de ser valido"
          ],
          passwordRules:[
              v => !!v || "La contraseña es requerida"
              v => v.length >= 8  || "La contraseña debe de contener al menos 8 caracteres"
          ]
       }
    }
 }
};
</script>
```